# Regex match the number in between numbers

Tags: regex, match, regex-lookarounds

I have a list of string containing time in the following format.

```
15 min 43 sec
```

I want to extract `43` only. I was practicing at http://regexr.com/ but could not find an answer. The answer i have come to right now is `\d+\s+min+\s+(\d*)+\s+sec` which is match the whole word. But it should match only `43`. Looking forward for the help soon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your regex actually is working. Of course, the complete expression matches. You get the `43` in the first *group*. This is also visible in the pop up at regexr.

Comment: How about `(\d+)\ssec{1}`

Comment: Please clarify how your question is related to Java. I would vote for removing the java tag, as your question is *only* about finding a regular expression. How this can be implemented in Java is a different topic. (And the `pattern-matching` and `regex-lookarounds` tags should also be removed, then.)

Comment: I cant use lookbehind. It is not supported in my tool.

Comment: Martin, Infact the regex is matching the whole line. I want to match only 43. Can you show it in regexr on how to match only 43 please. My tool uses java and hence tagged java. But my job is t just provide the regex to match 43

Comment: Scary Wombat your answer is matching 43 sec. I wanted only43

Comment: what programming language you are using to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

A rudimentary and fast solution can be... `\s(\d+)\s`
But try to find a better one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(\d+)(?=\s+sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern contains two **capturing groups** (for minutes and seconds), and allows for an arbitrary number of whitespaces inbetween the values. If only the seconds need to be extracted, one group would suffice.

**To extract the values, match against an input (using a `Matcher`) and read the value of the according group** (`matcher.group(n)`, where 1 is the first group):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s*min\\s*(\\d+)\\s*sec");
String[] data = {"15 min 43 sec", "15min 43sec", "15      min 43   sec"};
for (String d : data) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(d);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        int seconds = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    } else {
        System.out.println("no match: " + d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Peter I want regex solution and not java solution.But your answer is perfect though. Thanks